# Spring boot RepositoryRestResource validation are not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

when using **RepositoryRestResource** insted of create crud controller the validation are not working,

```
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank

    private String name;
}
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

}
```

[image]

If i create a crud controller and add

```
public Catrgory create(@Valid Category category){
    ....
}
```

the validation will work but i don't want this , i want to use **RepositoryRestResource**